# Invalid `Podfile` file: Invalid `RNFBDatabase.podspec` file: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../app/package.json - react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods, pod-install

I installed firebase like this in my react native project-->

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/database
```

and then when I tried installing the pods based on the documentation with this command -->

```
cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
```

I got the error below:

```
> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file:  [!] Invalid `RNFBDatabase.podspec` file:
> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../app/package.json.
```

Comment: Same here.. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've been at it for 2 days now, but I'm glad that I solved the problem. It was the missing dependency `@react-native-firebase/app` . The `@react-native-firebase/database` requires `@react-native-firebase/app` to be installed.